How to properly create a useable disk image for Virtual box?
I can create the disk image of a bootable Linux HDD by using sudo, but then it fails to boot in VirtualBox.  My steps are as follows:
dd if=/dev/sde  of=sda.img bs=1024 conv=noerror,sync
VBoxManage convertfromraw sda.img "sda.vdi" --format VDI

I thought maybe the problem was that I used sudo to create the image, but I tried without, sudo but permission was denied. I see that root owns the HDD.
What am I doing wrong?

You're forgetting the bootloader. As always and with any OS a bootloader is required, not just the system's partition. With BIOS/Legacy/CSM and a 'msdos' drive that would be at the MBR; with a new post-2012 UEFI system bootloaders are at the ESP (EFI System Partition). No, it has nothing to do with sudo.

And one has to wander why you're making things harder than they have to be... What wrong with installing the OS in Virtualbox and then using the virtual drive itself and/or the export feature?
